# Каким образом я могу вызывать функции Google Apps Script на своем сайте?

Tags: google-apps-script

Если вызывать функции возможно, то как в них передать данные? Например, как задать переменные и получить данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это слишком общий вопрос.

Представления о понятии `сайта` слишком разнообразны. Этот раздел знаний будет представляться как серверверное так и клиент-серверное взаимодействие.

Google Apps Script может взаимодействовать с внешним миром посредством двух основных интерфейсов.

[Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/) позволяет внешним сервисам взаимодействовать со скриптом на уровне REST. Легко, удобно, нет анонимных вызовов.

[HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) и [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service) позволяют через "внешние раздражители" ввиде запросов http отвечать на них классами HtmlOutput или TextOutput. Для точек входа используются зарезервированные функции doGet(e) и doPost(e). Скрипт должен быть опцбликован как веб-приложение. Удобно, легко, есть анонимные вызовы.

Comment: Не могу понять,  как подключить API к своему коду в php?

Comment: Пример для Execution API https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/php Вызов веб-приложения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086864/calling-google-app-script-from-php-using-curl Публикация веб-приложения https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxRY6PZqCug или см пост ниже.

Comment: А это только в гугл проекте или это можно сделать и на своем сервере?

Comment: Вам нужно создать на Диске Гугл проект Google Apps Script и опубликовать его либо как веб-приложение, либо как API executable. Далее, исходя из этой вилки, обращаться со своего сервера к скрипту. @zombic привел хороший пример веб-приложения.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Следуя [инструкции](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224162?hl=ru) вы создаёте скрипт. К примеру такой:

```
function doGet(e) {
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(e.parameter.a1+' '+e.parameter.a2);
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');
}
```

или такой:

```
function doGet(e) {
   // Print 'Hello world!'
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(e.parameter.a1+' '+e.parameter.a2);
 }
```

Далее сохраняем скрипт и в меню выбираем ***Публикация*** -> ***Развернуть как веб-приложение***, получаем ссылку вида

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec
```

к которой добавляем наши аргументы `?a1=Hello&a2=World!`, получаем

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec?a1=Hello&a2=World!
```

где

`a1=Hello` - первый переданный скрипту аргумент,

`a2=World!` - второй аргумент.

Далее, по первому варианту кода, в Google Disk создаётся doc-файл `Hello World!` или, по второму варианту кода, получаем на экране надпись `Hello World!`